# Netbeans 8 errs on phpunit-skelgen syntax

Tags: php, netbeans, phpunit

I am trying to automate my PHPUnit testing using the tool inside Netbeans. I cannot get the phpunit-skelgen running though. This is what Netbeans tries to execute:

```
"/usr/bin/php" "/var/home/brod/vendor/bin/phpunit-skelgen" "--test" "--" "Calculator" "/var/home/brod/projeto/calculadora.php" "CalculatorTest" "/var/home/brod/projeto/testes/calculadoraTest.php"
```

If I simply replace "--test" with "generate-test" in the command line, leaving the rest unchanged, my tests are created:

```
"/usr/bin/php" "/var/home/brod/vendor/bin/phpunit-skelgen" "generate-test" "--" "Calculator" "/var/home/brod/projeto/calculadora.php" "CalculatorTest" "/var/home/brod/projeto/testes/calculadoraTest.php"
```

Now, is there a simple way to tell Netbeans to use the correct syntax?

Answer (score 1):

Use the older version of phpunit or create a wrapper and point it to that

phpunit-skelgen.sh:

```
#!/bin/sh
/location/to/your/phpunit-skelgen generate-test $4 $5 $6 $7 $8
```

command line:

```
chmod +x phpunit-skelgen.sh
```

Comment: Thank you Daniel! I never thought of using a shell wrapper. It worked with a minor change: 

    /location/to/your/phpunit-skelgen generate-test $5 $6 $7 $8 $9

Comment: I was just having the same issue but no one has seemed to resolve it. Usually I wouldn't settle for such a hack but...so much to do, so little time to do it in! Glad it worked for you!

Comment: I thanked you publicly on the third chapter of my tutorial Agile Testing in PHP: http://dicas-l.com.br/brod/brod_201406031721.php (in Portuguese, though!).

Answer (score 0):

Here is PHP version of wrapper:

```
<?php

$phpunit_skelgen_path = 'C:\Users\YourUser\AppData\Roaming\Composer\vendor\phpunit\phpunit-skeleton-generator\phpunit-skelgen';

$php_path = 'C:\PHP\php.exe';

foreach ($argv as $i => $arg) {
    if ($arg === '--test') {
        $argv[$i] = 'generate-test';
    }
}

$arguments = implode(' ', array_slice($argv, 1));

system("$php_path $phpunit_skelgen_path $arguments");
```